# how to show the UIPopoverController when button clicked in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller

I have a problem with UIPopoverController. On button press I need to display the UIPopoverController. This is the code.

```
-(IBAction)hintButton:(id)sender{ 
CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40);
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
popoverContent.view = hintB;

popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = contentRect.size;
if(popoverController == nil){   //make sure popover isn't displayed more than once in the view
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popoverContent]; 

    [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    popoverController.delegate = self;
 }
```

}

When I press the button application crashes.

Comment: Instead of a UIViewController do UIPopoverController and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIPopoverController cannot be used for iPhone applications. It's only for iPad apps.

However, you can have this functionality by creating custom UIPopoverController. You can find a custom UIPopoverController sample [here](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover).

Let me know if you have any similar questions.

Thanks,

MinuMaster